# what is the second argument in date function meant for?

Tags: php, date

Can anyone please explain me the second argument of [*date*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function ?

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

What is it do,I mean what is it meant for ? I never used it except today when I had to do the following :

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Comment: its for the date\timestamp, it defaults to NOW, so you wont need it in that case

Answer (score 3):

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using
>   the given integer **timestamp** or the current time if no timestamp is
>   given. In other words, **timestamp** is optional and defaults to the
>   value of time().

So if you leave it blank, you will echo the current date in the chosen format.

If you do as you do in your example and specify a timestamp it will format the specified timestamp. Your **strtotime** function converts +1day to an integer or timestamp format.

Answer (score 2):

By default `date()` assumes you are referring to "now". If you want to use date with any other datetime other than "no" then you need to specify it using a timestamp.

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d") === date("Y-m-d", time())); // bool(true)
```

Comment: `date('y-m-d' + timestamp)` always adds to `now` ?

Answer (score 0):

This mean that you can represent unix time as string in any format. Unix time you can get from database or with strtotime.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter defaults to the current date/time.

So, if you want to print the current date, don't pass the second parameter:

```
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

If you want to print something other than the current date/time, like the date of one week from today:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
```